# Having a shell script refer to XCode build paths

Tags: xcode, git, shell, hudson, lcov

I have a shell script that runs lcov (test coverage) on an iOS project that I have Hudson. Hudson's copy of this project is derived from a Git repository. The way that I have set up now is that whenever the repo is updated or if someone manually builds the project in Hudson, Hudson would automatically run the app, and then run my shell script after the build is done. lcov can only be run after the app is not only built, but automatically run with some functional test tools. So, I cannot run the shell script as part of the build process, through XCode. It must be run after the app finishes building and running.

However, I would like to use this project in multiple Hudson jobs. Unfortunately, in each Hudson job, the iOS project is named differently. I would like to refer to the build path with some sort of environmental variable, but I don't know how to. Does anyone have any tips as to how to find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is really a Hudson question.  You can set "global variables" in your Hudson config and then invoke shell scripts, batch files, ant builds etc.  You can also set them dynamically on each invocation of your Hudson job.  Not sure exactly how to help you in your specific environment without more info.

Comment: What I ended up doing was using one of Hudson's built-in environment variables- $WORKSPACE, specifically. Apparently I can use those variables in my own shell scripts.